# Bitmap not Aligning Properly in Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been looking around on Google for quite some time and cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.

The problem is with painting a bitmap onto a panel. For some strange reason the entire bitmap seems to have an offset towards the upper-left of the panel.Which makes it confusing when building the map. As an extra note the bitmap was being painted on a panel larger than itself. (e.g. bitmap.dimensions == 64x64 and panel.dimensions == 512x512).

```
    private void redrawCityPanel()
    {
        Image cityImage = this.cityBitmap;

        Graphics panel_CityGraphics = this.panel_City.CreateGraphics();
        panel_CityGraphics.Clear(this.panel_City.BackColor);
        panel_CityGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        panel_CityGraphics.DrawImage(cityImage, panel_City.DisplayRectangle);
    }
```

Sorry about the confusion. I would post images but I haven't earned enough points.

Comment: Just figured out the solution. All you need to do is add the following line of code

Comment: panel_CityGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "draw the pixels as squares instead of points", but using NearestNeighbor will make your image look like crap if any resizing occurs. Try using HighQualityBicubic instead.

Comment: Hello Dr_Asik, before I applied the pixel offset. It looked like the entire bitmap was slightly shifted to the upper left of the panel. That was causing issues because I needed to have my pixels aligned so I could build the map (for a game) properly.

Comment: I'll reword the question so it make more sense.

Comment: For future visitors, it may be helpful to mention that you are drawing the bitmap at larger than normal size.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All I needed to do was set the pixel offset mode.

```
private void redrawCityPanel()
{
    Image cityImage = this.cityBitmap;

    Graphics panel_CityGraphics = this.panel_City.CreateGraphics();
    panel_CityGraphics.Clear(this.panel_City.BackColor);
    panel_CityGraphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

    panel_CityGraphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half; //Added

    panel_CityGraphics.DrawImage(cityImage, panel_City.DisplayRectangle);
}
```